# Survival Analysis in R - Transform Kaplan Meier Plot to X = continous variable, Y = P(survival), colored lines = Chosen Timepoints

Tags: r, ggplot2, survival-analysis, survival, survminer

In pursuit of visualizing the distribution of a continuous predictor by survival odds in the sample, I wish to transform the K-M plot as described in my title.

The idea is this way it is easy to see the full range of continuous values. I sacrifice the visualization of overall time distribution of survival, but using colors and maintaining P(Survival) on the y-axis, I could easily plot the 1 year, 5 year survival rate etcetera.

Note I am not looking for Cox visualization. I am interested in the data from a K-M function, i.e.:

```
km <- survfit(Surv(time, censor) ~ continuous.predictor, data = df)
ggsurvplot(km)
```

but with the x-axis as the continuous predictor and with lines colored by chosen points in time. Theoretically, this should just be a matter of making factored time the `strata` and `continuous.predictor` the new x-value.

However, I am not sure how to do this in R. I have used `survfit()` in the survival package and `ggsurvplot()` from `survminer` but is unclear if either support such a transformation.

Comment: Hi @purpleblade98 - as your question stands, we're limited in our ability to help. Could you edit your question to be reproducible and demonstrate your desired output? Some tips are here: [How to write a good R question with a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/r-language/articles/76995406/how-to-write-a-good-r-question-with-a-reproducible-example) - good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You could do this using the `predict` function on your model, supplying the values of the continuous variable and the times at which you wish to measure survival probability.

Let's use the `lung` example from the survival package, with `age` as the continuous variable of interest:

```r
library(survival)

model <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ age, data = lung)
```

Now we create a data frame of all ages 30 - 80 at follow up times of 6 months, 1 year and 5 years:

```r
newdata <- expand.grid(age = 30:80, time = c(182, 365, 5*365), status = 1)
```

We can feed this to `predict` and get the survival probabilities, with 95% confidence intervals:

```r
preds <- predict(model, newdata = newdata, type = 'expected', se.fit = TRUE)

newdata$pred <- exp(-preds$fit)
newdata$upper <- exp(-(preds$fit + 1.96 * preds$se.fit))
newdata$lower <- exp(-(preds$fit - 1.96 * preds$se.fit))
```

Now we can plot with vanilla ggplot:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(newdata, aes(age, pred, color = factor(time))) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymax = upper, ymin = lower, fill = factor(time)),
              alpha = 0.2, color = NA) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_fill_discrete('Time', labels = c('6 months', '1 year', '5 years')) +
  scale_color_discrete('Time', labels = c('6 months', '1 year', '5 years')) +
  scale_y_continuous('Survival probability', labels = scales::percent) +
  theme_minimal() +
  ggtitle(paste('Survival Probability according to age',
                'at 6 months, 1 year, 5 years'))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, but is it possible to do this with K-M descriptive probabilities of survival, rather than those predicted from a Cox model?

Comment: @purpleblade98 I don't really know what you mean. If you create a `survfit` object directly with a formula containing a continuous predictor, it will just create a stratum for each unique value of the continuous predictor. For a genuinely continuous variable, this means there will only be a single observation at each value, so there won't _be_ any KM statistics. You could bin the continuous data I suppose, but then it isn't continuous. Survival estimates on continuous variables require a CoxPH as far as I know. Unless you can share a link to something similar.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently published an article on this topic called "Visualizing the (causal) effect of a continuous variable on a time-to-event outcome" (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC10392888/). It describes multiple different ways to visualize the effect of continuos variables on the survival probability. For example, this is the survival area plot:

[image: survival_area_plot]

You can create this and other graphs similar to this using the `contsurvplot` R-package, available on CRAN: https://robindenz1.github.io/contsurvplot/

If you want the continuous variable on the x-axis, the survival probability on the y-axis and colored lines for some specific points in time you can use the `plot_surv_at_t` function. In this case, the only difference to the answer given by Allan Cameron is that it allows you to include adjustment variables in the Cox model as well.